# How to display ArrayList Objects in GridView in Android in fragment

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments

I am trying to learn how to display a gridview with 3 columns in a fragment.  The values are from the strings.xml file as an array list.  When I run the application it crashes.  Can anyone help me to display the values in 3 columns namely Places, Description and Time.  I can`t proceed on how to display the read values in the gridview.

```
My Code are as follows:
**Strings.XML**
    <string-array name="PlacesName">
        <item>Durban</item>
        <item>Paris</item>
        <item>HongKong</item>
        <item>Canada</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Description">
        <item>Description1</item>
        <item>Description2</item>
        <item>Description3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="ScheduleDate">
        <item>12/1/2015</item>
        <item>13/2/2015</item>
        <item>14/4/2015</item>
        <item>15/5/2015</item>
    </string-array>

**Fragment**

    */
public class FlightFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView grid;

    public FlightFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        grid.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return view;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<Schedule> list;
        private Context context;

        MyAdapter() {
            list = new ArrayList();
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            String[] tempPlaces = resources.getStringArray(R.array.PlacesName);
            String[] tempDate = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ScheduleDate);
            String[] tempDescription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Description);
            for(int count=0;count<4;count++ ){
                Schedule tempSchedule = new Schedule(tempPlaces[count],tempDate[count],tempDescription[count]);
                list.add(tempSchedule);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Schedule tempSchedule = list.get(position);
            TextView textView;
            if (convertView == null){
                textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            }
            else{
                textView = (TextView) convertView;
            }
            textView.setText(tempSchedule.Place);
            return textView;
        }
    }

    class Schedule {
        String Place;
        String ScheduleTime;
        String Description;

        Schedule(String place, String scheduleTime, String description ) {
            this.Description = description;
            this.Place = place;
            this.ScheduleTime = scheduleTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.ts.FlightFragment$MyAdapter.(FlightFragment.java:51)
>               at com.ts.FlightFragment.onCreateView(FlightFragment.java:38)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is the error message on log ?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils please see error message

Comment: Have you assign context in your adapter ??

Comment: @ArkarAung this is where I am stuck.  Can you please have a look at the code and tell me how I should correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you forgot to assign context in your adapter. You can pass it via constructor. In activity, you can simply use `this` as a context. In your case, in fragment, need to pass `getActivity()` as a context.

```
public class FlightFragment extends Fragment {

GridView grid;

public FlightFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flight, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
    grid.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    return view;

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Schedule> list;
    private Context context;

    MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        list = new ArrayList();
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        String[] tempPlaces = resources.getStringArray(R.array.PlacesName);
        String[] tempDate = resources.getStringArray(R.array.ScheduleDate);
        String[] tempDescription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Description);
        for(int count=0;count<4;count++ ){
            Schedule tempSchedule = new Schedule(tempPlaces[count],tempDate[count],tempDescription[count]);
            list.add(tempSchedule);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Schedule tempSchedule = list.get(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_row, parent, false);
        }
        TextView placeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
        TextView scheduleDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_date);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        placeName.setText(tempSchedule.Place);
        scheduleDate.setText(tempSchedule.ScheduleTime);
        description.setText(tempSchedule.Description);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In grid_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schedule_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**
You need to create `grid_row.xml` which is including 3 textviews. Inflate that layout on `getView` and then return it.
You can improve performance to avoid `findViewById()` by using [ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) .

Comment: Using MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this); is giving error message MyAdapter (android.content.context) cannot be aplied

Comment: Thanks @Arkar , Can you please tell me what is wrong in the code  as it is is not displaying all 3 columns...  I have set the numcolumns to 3, however, I could not figure out how to pass all 3 array lists values so I just did   textView.setText(tempSchedule.Place);

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code as you describe. It shows 3 column with your code. Please show me your xml.

Comment: It is only showing the places not the other 3 columns

Comment: You mean you want to show place, description and schedule date in each column ??

Comment: Yes, I want to show place, description and schedule date in each column

Comment: Please see how I edited your piece of code... With that I still can`t figure out how to display all 3 column values, as I have done " return textViewPlace "but rather have to return all 3 textviews

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please mark as correct if this answer is useful for you :)

Comment: I have created the grid_row.xml (see edited code) and added the piece of code you just gave.  The app crashes.  See edited code to see crash error message.

Comment: Pardon me. Forget to assign to `convertView`. I've updated it.

Comment: Oops sorry, it is now working but still not displaying things correctly and in the columns expected!  I want to have 3 columns and in each column it must display the text in the strings.xml file in rows...

Comment: I think it should be displaying 3 columns which contain 3 text view in each.

Comment: I want them to be displayed in 3 columns and each column should contain the data in rows... the way it is displaying right now, it does not show 3 columns and data in rows in the columns

Comment: It is displaying only one column with 4 rows... it is not right

Comment: Are you sure you added `android:numColumns="3"` to `<GridView>` ??

Comment: Is it because of the  Schedule tempSchedule = list.get(position);? and It`s not filling in the data from the strings.xml file?

Comment: list is added data from strings.xml. You did it in adapter's constructor. Right !

Comment: Yes, I changed <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"> to horizontal, now it is displaying 3 columns but only with one row....

Comment: It is displaying the first row only

Comment: It is displaying data from the strings.xml, bur only the first row and not all rows out there

Comment: I think you didn't notice my updated code. I removed `else` block in `getView` method.

Comment: Thanks @Arkar Aung.  This has solved my issue.  God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem

> context in MyAdapter is null

Solution:-

Pass context to MyAdapter constructor like this:-

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
```

And change this in MyAdapter class

```
MyAdapter(Context context) {
this.context=context;
......
}
```

Comment: Using MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this); is giving error message MyAdapter (android.content.context) cannot be aplied

Comment: Should use `getActivtiy()` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks @android-mantra, however, it is showing only one column...I am sorry for asking sily questions as I am doing that for the first time